# Passing jQuery slider value onto Django form

Tags: jquery, django, forms, slider

I'm having a difficult time extracting a jQuery slider value in a Django form when it is submitted. I can pass a value to it from the URL on through the outer and inner urls.py and views.py when the page is accessed or refreshed, but I can't include the slider value in the form upon submission. Needless to say I have tried numerous methods to extract the value, including jQuery post methods and AJAX, but nothing I've tried works.

First, I created a simple form (forms.Form), and then later tried using a model form, expecting more control, but returned to a forms.Form. My form.py is:

```
    class ChoiceForm(forms.Form):
        '''Checkboxes.'''
        GeoJunk = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=True)
        ...
        '''Field for jQuery slider widget value. I initially don’t care if it is hidden, especially during troubleshooting.'''
        slider_field = forms.CharField(max_length=4, required=False)
```

My views.py is complex, but the essence is:

```
    def profile_list(request, sort_arg='default', latlonzoom='39.991622,-105.250098,15', choice='7', rangefactor='0'):

    request_user = request.user

    ''' Initialize slider value. '''
    slider_value = 0

    if request.method == 'POST':
    choice_form = ChoiceForm(request.POST, prefix="choice")
    if choice_form.is_valid(): 
        bit1 = choice_form.cleaned_data['GeoJunk']
        ...
        '''The slider value submitted from form.'''
        slider_state = choice_form.cleaned_data['slider_value']
    else:
        choice_form = ChoiceForm()

    …
    return render(request, "junkster/pages/home.html", add_csrf(request, MEDIA_URL=MEDIA_URL, STATIC_URL=STATIC_URL, request_user=request_user, waypoints=waypoints, librarypoints=librarypoints, gs_waypoints=gs_waypoints, search_flag=search_flag, lat=lat, lon=lon, zoom=zoom, waypoints_count=waypoints_count, librarypoints_count=librarypoints_count, gs_waypoints_count=gs_waypoints_count, choice_form=choice_form, sort_arg=sort_arg, latlonzoom=latlonzoom, choice=choice, rangefactor=rangefactor, slider_state=slider_state
    ))
```

The templates are complicated, but in essence start with choice.html and extend eventually onto base-geomap.html:

base-geomap.html:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}"{% if LANGUAGE_BIDI %} dir="rtl"{% endif %}>
    {% load pages_tags mezzanine_tags i18n staticfiles %}

    <head>
    …
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "junkster/css/jquery-ui.css" %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "junkster/css/jquery-ui.min.css" %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "junkster/css/jquery-ui.theme.css" %}"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "junkster/css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" %}"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "junkster/css/jquery-ui.slider.css" %}"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "junkster/css/jquery-ui-timepicker-  addon.css" %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "junkster/css/jquery.simple-dtpicker.css" %}">
    {% endcompress %}

    {% compress js %}
    <script src="{% static 'mezzanine/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static "js/bootstrap.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static "js/bootstrap-extras.js" %}"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "junkster/js/jquery-ui.js" %}"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "junkster/js/jquery-min.js" %}"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "junkster/js/jquery-ui-min.js" %}"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "junkster/js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js" %}"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "junkster/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" %}"></script> 
    {% endcompress %}
    …
    <script>
    //Follows: var URL = "{% url 'junkster:profile_list' default' latlonzoom choice rangefactor %}";
    var URL = "{% url 'junkster:profile_list' 'default' '39.99, -105.25,15' '7' '2' %}";
    </script>
    <script>
    $( function() {
    //Array of slider values.
    var valMap = ['1mi', '4mi', 'All'];
        $( "#slider_vertical" ).slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: false,
        max: valMap.length - 1,
        //Set initial value to the URL rangefactor.
        // This will be a value of [0, 1, 2]. 
        value: {{rangefactor}},
        //"slide" or "change" work equally well.
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            //Index values of [0, 1, 2].
            $("#val").text(ui.value);
            //Mapped values of ['1mi', '4mi', 'All'].
            $("#nlVal").text(valMap[ui.value]);
            //Shows mapped value of slider on top, e.g., "1mi," 
            // rather than rangefactor value "0."
            $( "#amount" ).val( valMap[ui.value] );
            /Affects the HTML template "slider_value" input field.
            $('#id_slider_field').val(valMap[ui.value]);

            //Does not work.
            //$('#id_slider_field').attr('value', ui.value); 
        }
    });
    //Shows the mapped value of slider on top upon startup.
    $( "#amount" ).val( valMap[$( "#slider_vertical" ).slider( "value" )] );
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    …
```

choiceform.html:

```
    {% extends "junkster/pages/geolist.html" %}
    {% block choiceform %}
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <!--Keep checkboxes in list.-->
        {{ choice_form.as_ul }}
        <input type="submit" name="choicevalue" value="Submit" />
        <br><br>

        <!-- -----JQuery Slider.---- -->
        <b>Range of View:</b>
        <!--Mapped value display on top of slider.-->
        <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0;  color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold; margin-left:3em;">
        <!--Slider widget.-->
        <div id="slider_vertical" style="height:12em; margin-left:3em;"></div>
        <br>
        <!--For diagnostics.-->
        <!--”rangefactor” should assume the slider value.-->
        rangefactor = {{ rangefactor }}<br><br>
        <!--”slider_valuer” is the slider value from view.-->
        slider_value = {{ slider_value }}<br>
        <!--This html field does show the value of the slider.-->
        <input type="text" id="id_slider_field", name="slider_field">
        </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

The last part of the choiceform.html has an input text field that does show the changed value of the slider, but I can’t submit this with the Django form fields, unless I’m in error.

I wish that the jQuery functions could implement something in the final template such as:

```
    rangefactor = slider_value
    a href="{% url 'junkster:profile_list' 'default' latlonzoom choice rangefactor %}">Wish this would happen!</a>
```

I appreciate anyone with suggestions, as I’ve tried unsuccessfully to extract the slider value along with the Django form’s other checkbox values.

Walter Goedecke

Comment: that's a lot of code. Please post only the most relevent bits. Namely your javascript code that makes the ajax request and the python view that handles it.

Comment: It is much; I'm not sure if I can prune the code now.

Answer (score 0):

I did find the solution. One has to create another hidden text field withing the form html template; not a Django form field.

Again, the slider jQuery widget in the parent template:

```
    <script>
        $( function() {
            //Array of slider values.
            var valMap = ['1mi', '4mi', '16mi', 'All'];
            $( "#slider_vertical" ).slider({
            orientation: "vertical",
            range: false,
            max: valMap.length - 1,
            //Set initial value to the URL rangefactor.
            // This will be a value of [0, 1, 2, 3]. 
            value: {{rangefactor}},
            //"slide" or "change" work equally well.
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                //Index values of [0, 1, 2, 3].
                $("#val").text(ui.value);
                //Mapped values of ['1mi', '4mi', '16mi', 'All'].
                $("#nlVal").text(valMap[ui.value]);
                //Shows mapped values of slider on top.
                $( "#amount" ).val( valMap[ui.value] );
                $('#slider_field').val(ui.value);
                }
            });
            //Shows the mapped values on top upon startup.
            $( "#amount" ).val( valMap[$( "#slider_vertical" ).slider( "value" )] );
        });
    </script>
```

Child template - choiceform.html:

```
    <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ choice_form.as_ul }}
    <!--This hidden html field captures the value of the slider.-->
    <input type="hidden" id="slider_field", name="slider_field">

    <!-- -----JQuery Slider.---- -->
    <div class=title7>Range of View:</div>
    <!--Mapped value display on top of slider.-->
    <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style=...">
    <!--Slider widget.-->
    <div id="slider_vertical" style=..."></div>

    <input type="submit" name="choicevalue" value="Submit" action="{% url 'junkster:profile_list' sort_arg latlonzoom choice rangefactor %}" />
```

The special "submit" button sends the focus back to the view, with the appropriate arguments.

In the view, the choiceform.html field which picks up the slider value is accessed as such:

```
    ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        choice_form = ChoiceForm(request.POST, prefix="choice")
        #Check if form is valid:
        if choice_form.is_valid(): 
        #Get the slider value from the special form text field.
        try:
            slider_value = request.POST['slider_field']
            if str(slider_value) != '':
                rangefactor = slider_value
            if rangefactor == 'NaN' or numpy.isnan(int(rangefactor)):
                rangefactor = '0'
        except:
            rangefactor = '0'
```

"rangefactor" only copies the slider value, "slider_value," when it is changed, hence the error trapping routine, as a NaN value crashes the program when it ends up in the URL call within the choiceform.html again calling the view.